# running low on disk space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, disk-space

I am using Windows 7 installed on a 120 Gb SSD.

Today I have noticed, that there is only 2GB of free space left on it, so I started to clean things up.

I realized that only my user profile takes more than 20GB of free space so I checked what is going on and found `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows` was taking more than 10GB only.
So I googled and found a solution to run the *disk cleanup* from windows. After the scan was complete the new size of the folder is 8,8 GB.
When I open it and check files one by one, they take only 100MB only in total. (*yes, I have the show hidden files/folders enabled*)

So my questions are:

1. What is this?
2. How can I get rid of this?
3. How can I free up some more space by deleting or migrating things to
   my HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're showing hidden files, folders and drives but you *are* hiding **protected operating system files**.

I don't know that you can get rid of much in that folder, but this is what I suggest to clean up disk space:

- [Windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) is a great tool for finding big files/folders on your hard drive.
- [Ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) is a great tool to clean up detritus in your filesystem.

Comment: Ccleaner solved the issue. As I saw the report, they were some sort of temporary files in there. It has also closed my 120 opened firefox tabs as well (this hurt a bit), but at least I have some free space now.

Answer (score 1):

You do have a substantial amount of data there.  I'd recommend you do two things...

1) Perform another Disk Cleanup, this time click on Clean Up System Files, click on the More Options tab, click on the System Restore and Shadow Copies Clean up button, select Delete, Okay, and Delete.

2) The only cleaner I've used which cleans up temporary files very well is [Auslogic Speed Boost](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/boost-speed/).  It's a free download and the temp file cleanup is also free.  There are other features which must be paid for but I'm not recommending that.  Just download the software, install it (read everything as you install, say no if you do not agree).  Run the application and tell it to recover your temp space.  After that you can stop the program from running (it likes to run in background and will be on the task bar) and it will be there the next time you feel the urge to purge.

Comment: If You would have posted this earlier, I would have chosen this solution. CCleaner already did this but since I was not patient enough to read the details, I managed to delete some files with it that I shouldn't have. Next time I will try this program as well. Thank You for the answer.