# Low disk space on drive C with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

I have a "haier laptop y11b" it have 2 disks:

1. SSD card of 29 GB, C drive on which windows 10 is installed
2. HDD 465 GB

Previously Windows 8.1 was installed on this laptop and all the apps were installed on drive D. It was fine, showing no problems. There was always 13 GB or more free space available on C.

Then I installed windows 10. After installation on drive C, 15 GB was still free.

Then due to low space on C, I installed all of my apps on drive D, but space was still occupied on drive C. And now only 938 MB is free on C, and its marked red with error "low space on c".

Now I don't understand what is consuming drive C's space in windows 10, while there was no such problem with windows 8.1. How do I free out the space on C, while only windows 10 is installed there?

---

I downloaded WinDirStat and scanned C. I found a few large folders and files:

- Windows\WinSxS = 8.0 GB
- Windows\Installer = 3.1 GB
- ProgramData\Package cache = 1.2 GB
- pagefile.sys = 1.4GB
- hiberfile.sys = 803MB

[image: windirstat image]

Can I delete or move any file to other drives just to free up space on my SSD?

Comment: Use any of the dozens of available tools to figure out what's using your disk space. Spacemonger is nice, so is Treesize.

Comment: You'll need to use a disc analyser, such as the free `WinDirStat` ([Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) version available) to find out what is consuming all the space. I suspect that even though you install software on `D:` the defaults will still save data and work files to `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%` or `%USERPROFILE%`, which will still be on `C:`, unless you do something to change this. The data directories are often very much larger than the executables that you have installed on `D:`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running low on disk space](http://superuser.com/questions/921269/running-low-on-disk-space)

Comment: The "Windows/installer" path is the biggest bang for your buck. You cannot remove it, but you can hard-link it: ( http://superuser.com/questions/707767/how-can-i-free-up-drive-space-from-the-windows-installer-folder-without-killing ) using `mklink /d /h <link-the original path> <destination path>`. *All* (delete, remove etc) file operations on the link path are then redirected to the destination path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pagefile.sys` is an important Windows file. Delete that, and your computer **won't** restart. So you'd rather not delete it. ;)

This article explains WinSxS: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/winsxs-folder-windows-7-8

So basically, there is a way to clean the WinSxS folder. You might want to run the `Disk Cleanup` tool that comes with Windows or download a cleanup tool, such as `CCleaner`. From there, do not forget to uninstall useless apps and delete files you do not use.

There is also ways to tell your computer to install every apps automatically on your drive D:.

> To change the registry, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Start Registry Editor by entering `Regedit` in the search All programs.
> 2. Locate the following: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
> 3. Right click on the value named `ProgramFilesDir` & change the default value `C:\Program Files` to the path you want to install all
>      your programs in.
> 4. Click OK and Exit.
>
> [Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343)

Assuming you are using a Windows 10 64-bit, make this change as well:

1. Press the Windows key + R on your keyboard type `regedit` and press Enter key.
2. Go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
3. Change the Path in DWORDs `ProgramFilesDir`, `ProgramFilesDir (x86)` to the new path.

### Little reminder

This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore the registry, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
[322756: How to back up and restore the registry in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756/)

> If you'd like to move Windows Apps, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Press Windows key + I on your keyboard
> 2. Go in `System`, then Storage in the left menu
> 3. Select new Path in `New apps with save to` (Refer to picture)
>
> [image]
>
> [Source](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-windows-10-apps-external-drive)

You can also Move already installed apps. The procedure is almost the same.

> Press Ctrl + I to bring up the Settings menu. Now click System, then select Apps & features (Or Installed Apps) from the left-hand navigation.
>
> Here you will find a list of all apps and programs installed on your system. Note that this move method will only work for apps that you have installed – that means those which were pre-installed can’t be moved.
>
> Scroll to the app that you want to move and select it from the list. Now, click Move. Select the new drive location from the dropdown, then click Move.
>
> [image]
>
> [Source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/move-installed-apps-programs-windows-10/)

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 Because he is running Windows 10, it is possible to move Windows Store apps to another drive too, using Settings.

Comment: I changed the ProgramFilesDir to new path and restart my system, I tried to install one application and it was installed correctly on new path by default, then i changed the ProgramFilesDir (x86) to the new location and restart the pc and again tried to install few application, but as i try to open any application this error is displayed " windows can not find this make sure you typed the name correctly" the i tried to restore my  system to an earliar restore point, but the same error that windows can not find this, even i am not able to open the registry ????????

Comment: should ireinstall the windows or there is any solution????

Comment: @Fleet Command Sir please will you tell me how to move windows store applications to other drive?????

Comment: @Sanakhan, I have edited my answer so you will be able to move apps from Windows 10 to another Drive.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Pagefile:

1. It is vital to windows. It is a file that Windows uses for RAM operations when your RAM is 100% consumed. Having no pagefile would cause your machine to crash or have serious issues when you run out of RAM. Having said that, removing it will **NOT** stop your computer from restarting. Windows will just recreate the file.
2. You *can* move the pagefile to a different drive to save space on C. To do that:

   - Right click on your start menu and select "System".
   - Click "Advanced System Settings" on the left.
   - On the "Advanced" tab, click "Settings" under "Performance".
   - On the "Advanced" tab, click "Change...".
   - Uncheck "Automatcially manage paging file size for all drives".
   - Select the "C" drive, select "No paging file" and click "Set".
   - Select the "D" drive, select "System managed size" and click "Set".
   - Click OK and when prompted to restart, do it.

Comment: and what about the "package cache" and "installer" folder in windows, can I move these two to another drive to free up space?????

Comment: No, however you can move C:\Windows\Temp to another drive as well. See:

https://www.howtogeek.com/285710/how-to-move-windows-temporary-folders-to-another-drive/

Comment: I did the same as you described to move the page file, but even after restart it is still there on c drive, and instantly C drive is more ocuupied about 1.5 GB. and when I restarted my PC this error was displayed " windows created a temporary paging file on your computer because of a problem that occured with your paging file configuration when you started your computer. the total paging size for all drives may be some what larger then you specified"

Comment: even each time I restart the computer or go to the "Advance system settings/advance/performance/settings" this error is displayed..

Comment: The issue is Windows can't write the file to your D drive. Probably a permissions issue. You can revert the settings and you'll be in the same boat you were in. I can't help you troubleshoot the perms issues. Sorry.

Comment: Finally I have reinstalled windows and now i am about to install only few necessary applications. I was thinking about not to install any of the antivirus programe as the windows 10 contain a a built in antivirus "windows defender".and moreover to have more space on C drive as it also occupies about 1.5 GB, So I waanna ask that is it necessary to install any of the antivirus programe or windows defender is enough for security of my system?????  "while I have already installed the free version of MalwareByte:"

Comment: Here is a guide about if you need the package cache https://superuser.com/questions/455853/can-i-delete-the-folder-c-programdata-package-cache

Answer (score 0):

This article gives a solution - [Low Disk Space on Recovery D Partition](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/low-disk-space-on-recovery-d-partition-4348.html)

1. Use Disk Management in Windows to extend volume.
2. Turn off System Protection to the target partition more space.
   3 Run Windows Disk Cleanup or other third-party cleaning software.